# Como obter um número aleatório em Kotlin?

Tags: java, random, kotlin, números-aleatórios

Como eu posso obter um número randômico entre dois valores? Tal como ruby faz com `rand(0..n)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Existem algumas maneiras de resolver esse problema:

#### Um método normal:

A primeira e mais intuitiva é criar uma função que retorna um número aleatório usando a classe `java.util.Random`:

```
import java.util.Random

val random = Random()

fun rand(from: Int, to: Int) : Int {
    return random.nextInt(to - from) + from // from(incluso) e to(excluso)
}
```

#### Funções extensivas:

Outra maneira mais interessante é usar funções extensivas:

```
fun ClosedRange<Int>.random() = 
     Random().nextInt(endInclusive - start) +  start
```

Logo em seguida você pode usar da seguinte maneira:

```
(0..10).random() // => retorná um númeor entre 0 e 9 (incluso)
```

> Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45685026/how-can-i-get-a-random-number-in-kotlin

Comment: Achei esse método por funções extensivas muito intrigante. Muito bom conhecer mais e mais de Kotlin só em ler respostas